# how to save data without html form into mysql database in django

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, database

I want to add data to mysql database in django without using any kind of form in post method. I want to hard code the data and store it in the database. I dont want to store it from phpmyadmin and want to code it I have alrady made my models.py file. this has created the table "offesnses" in the database.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import int_list_validator
# Create your models here.

class offenses(models.Model):
    oid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=20)
    assigned_to = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    categories = models.TextField(null=True)
    category_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    policy_category_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    security_category_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    close_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    closing_user = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    closing_reason_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    credibility = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    relevance = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    severity = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    magnitude = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    destination_networks = models.TextField(null=True)
    source_network = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    device_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    event_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    flow_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    inactive = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    last_updated_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    local_destination_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    offense_source = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    offense_type = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    protected = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    follow_up = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    remote_destination_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    source_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=20)
    username_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    source_address_ids = models.TextField(null=True)
    local_destination_address_ids = models.TextField(null=True)
    domain_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "offenses"
```

I want to save response_body data into database.for e.g. id,description etc

views.py

```
response_body = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

for j in response_body:
    print(j['id'])


context = {
    'ids': [j['id'] for j in response_body],
    'response': response_body,
    'dict_values': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
}

return render(request, 'table.html', context)
```

I surfed the internet and all i can find is inserting data through a form which is not my requirement.

New to django and python any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? You have the data, why can't you create a model instance and save it?

Comment: check this out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#create
If you want to do everything by hand, you wont even need a views.py just create a script and run it. example to create a db entry with the django ORM: `offenses.objects.create(description="lala",etc)`. Just read the django docs it will help you. If you want to create multiple entries use a for loop. btw you should write offenses with a capital "O".

Comment: And note of course that creating instances directly is fully covered in [part 2 of the official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api).

Comment: I did this and now it gives me this error. I just want to add it only once `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '4767' for key 'PRIMARY'")`